# How to sum up similar rows?

Tags: r

I want to calculate the mean of `m` for all ages and the mean of `f` for all ages then subtract it from the original values.

```
data <- data.frame(height=c(96,72,100,45),age=c(1,2,1,2),sex=c("m","f","f","m"))
data
    height age sex
1     96   1   m
2     72   2   f
3    100   1   f
4     45   2   m
```

desired output:

```
 data
    height age sex mean  dif
1     96   1   m    70.5  25.5
2     72   2   f    86     -14
3    100   1   f     86    14
4     45   2   m    70.5   -25.2
```

Comment: Your `dif` values seem to be wrong for males.

Comment: Did you do any search at all ?? you can simply find the answer by searching mean by ... Anyhow you can get the mean of m for example by doing `mean(data$height[data$sex == "m"])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a grouping in `dplyr` this is quite easy:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(height),
         dif = height - mean)
```

> ```
> Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
> Groups: sex [2]
>
>   height   age    sex  mean   dif
>    <dbl> <dbl> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     96     1      m  70.5  25.5
> 2     72     2      f  86.0 -14.0
> 3    100     1      f  86.0  14.0
> 4     45     2      m  70.5 -25.5
> ```